# Import from other module

Tags: java, maven

I write project using `Java` and `Maven`. In project I have many modules. My problem is that I can not import classes from other module.

My project structure looks like this:

```
Project
 |_ module1
    |_ src
       |_ com.xyz.project.md1
          |_ Person.java
    |_ pom.xml <- pom of module1
 |_ module2
    |_ src
       |_ com.xyz.project.md2
          |_ Robot.java
    |_ pom.xml <- pom of module2
 |_ pom.xml <- main Project pom
```

`module1` and `module2` are `Modules` in my project, which are registred in `pom.xml` - main Project pom

And when I am in `Person.java` from `module1` I want import the `Robot.java` from `module2` but I can not do this with `import com.xyz.project.md2.Robot`. **Why ?**

Comment: Doesn't each module have its own pom.xml? You should declare dependencies there.

Comment: Yup I added it some seconds ago. Refresh page

Comment: Dear downvoters, can You tell me why You give downvote ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Declare dependency to module2 in module1/pom.xml, something like this:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>XX</groupId>
                <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Even declaring the module dependency I cant import from the dependent module

Comment: The **SNAPSHOT** value refers to the 'latest' code along a development branch, and provides no guarantee the code is stable or unchanging. Conversely, the code in a 'release' version (any version value without the suffix **SNAPSHOT**) is unchanging.

In other words, a **SNAPSHOT **version is the 'development' version before the final 'release' version. The **SNAPSHOT ** is "older" than its release.

Comment: Unless you are managing the versions of the module independently, you can use <version>${project.version}</version> so you never have to change the POM when the project version changes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the project of module2 as dependency (maven dependency) in the project of module1. multimodules doesn't mean that all modules have automatically dependency to each other

The mechanism in Maven that handles multi-module projects does the following:

- Collects all the available modules to build
- Sorts the projects into the correct build order
- Builds the selected projects in order

Answer (score 2):

In build.gradle of module 2:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(":module1")) {
        transitive = false
    }
     ...
     //Other dependencies
     ...
}
```

`transitive = false` ensures dependencies of dependencies are not imported . Only your source part is imported

N.B. - Though the question uses Maven, but most of us use Gradle.